# Way to select checkbox Tab in create envelope api and read in formdata api is not consistent

Tags: docusignapi

I am working with predefined template. Template has checkboxes to capture user's communication preference with following data labels -

```
COMMUNICATION_PREF-FAX
COMMUNICATION_PREF-EMAIL
COMMUNICATION_PREF-PHONE
```

In create envelop API call if I want to select a particular checbox for example EMAIL then I have to pass following in request body
`POST /envelopes`

```
"checkboxTabs": [
    {
        "tabLabel": "COMMUNICATION_PREF-EMAIL",
        "selected": "true"
    }
]
```

And after signing is complete when I read form fields using formdata api `/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/form_data` I get following

```
{
    "name": "COMMUNICATION_PREF-EMAIL",
    "value": "X",
    "originalValue": "X"
}
```

As you can see that checkbox state (checked or unchecked) is represented differently in both case. Value is set `selected=true` is not consistent with how its read back `value = "X"` I tried passing `value = "X"` in create envelope api but it doesn't work.

This inconsistency is problem for the calling application. Should it store checkbox state as true/false or X / empty.

Its not possible to apply translation logic (like treat X as selected) because while reading formdata, field type information (whether it's checkbox or not) is not available.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: If the answer below was helpful, be sure to upvote and accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of form_data try this endpoint and include recipients,tabs as a qp:

`GET /accounts/[account_id]/envelopes/[envelope_id]include=recipients,tabs`.

The response object will contain exactly what you're looking for. Here is a sample:

```
{
    "status": "completed",
    ...
    "recipients": {
        "signers": [
            {
                "tabs": {
                    "checkboxTabs": [
                        {
                            "name": "",
                            "tabLabel": "Checkbox 105f25...0b2",
                            "selected": "true",
                            "shared": "false",
                            "requireInitialOnSharedChange": "false",  
                             ...

}
```

If you are hellbent on using the formData API, keep reading:

That formData API should return field type information within the `name` property. Basic string manipulation will enable you to discern the type. Here's a sample response object from an envelope I created...

```
{
    "formData": [...]
    "envelopeId": "7719639c-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-c847ebebb9c6",
    "status": "completed",
    "sentDateTime": "2020-05-29T00:13:00.0000000Z",
    "recipientFormData": [
        {
            "formData": [
                {
                    "name": "Checkbox 105f257e-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-03bae25e70b2 | tabGroups: [\"Checkbox Group 9620de9a-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-dbf6c90e98af\"]",
                    "value": "X"
                },
                ...
            ],
            "recipientId": "85c97d0b-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-fcc000c6400e",
            "name": "Name",
            "email": "test@test.com",
            "SignedTime": "...",
            "DeliveredTime": "..."
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks @matthew for suggesting alternative api. Downside of this is I will need loop through all documents of envelop and for each make the  ```/{documentId}/tabs``` api call. Is there any other api at envelop level to retrieve form data for all docs in the envelope?

Comment: I updated my response. This should work exactly as you intend. Be sure to upvote and accept. Thanks!